# Use jenkins api with basic auth behind htaccess auth

Tags: .htaccess, jenkins

I am having a problem that I cant auth to Jenkins when sending api requests, because I cant set the basic auth header, as it is already used to pass the htaccess basic auth.

I am not the maintainer of the project and the jenkins, so I cant remove the htaccess auth, or add my ip to allowed. How can I still get authenticated to send requests?